# How to automate confirm dialog inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to call an API using Postman, but unfortunately I can't because we have implemented a confirm dialog that blocks the api.
[image]

I have our credentials for `username` and `password`. But I would like just to ask if it's possible to automate or programmatically fill the `username` and `password` and auto-submit using Javscript or ReactJS?

```
axios.get('https://test.com/sample-response')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: It's called Basic Auth (https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) you can pass the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

[Using axios interceptors to add the basic auth header to every request](https://sabljakovich.medium.com/basic-authentication-with-axios-nodejs-browser-cfabe08ced39). For example:

```js
const username = 'dd';
const password = '##';
const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');

axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  config.headers['Authorization'] = `Basic ${token}`;
  return config;
});

axios.get('https://example.com')
.then(response => {
  // handle success
})
.catch(error => {
  // handle error
});
```

I hope this helps you with your query.